# Compiling module with external toolchain

Tags: linux, makefile, arm, toolchain

I created the make file

```
    obj-m += hello.o

all:
    make -C /home/developer/Desktop/xukr-20120201-omap3/linux-2.6.37-tn M=/home/developer/Desktop/module_test  modules

clean:
    make -C /home/developer/Desktop/xukr-20120201-omap3/linux-2.6.37-tn M=/home/developer/Desktop/module_test clean
```

Then, i found a simple hello program

```
#define __KERNEL__         /* We're part of the kernel */
#define MODULE             /* Not a permanent part, though. */

/* Standard headers for LKMs */
#include <linux/modversions.h> 
#include <linux/module.h>  

#include <linux/tty.h>      /* console_print() interface */

/* Initialize the LKM */
int init_module()
{
  console_print("Hello, world - this is the kernel speaking\n");
  /* More normal is printk(), but there's less that can go wrong with 
     console_print(), so let's start simple.
  */

  /* If we return a non zero value, it means that 
   * init_module failed and the LKM can't be loaded 
   */
  return 0;
}


/* Cleanup - undo whatever init_module did */
void cleanup_module()
{
  console_print("Short is the life of an LKM\n");
}
```

And i tried to compile on command line with this

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=angstrom-linux-gnueabi-
```

And i get this error

```
/bin/sh: angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found
```

What is wrong with this? i am really new at this.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Use `$(MAKE)` not `make` inside a `Makefile`

Comment: You really should acquire fluency with user-level Linux command line utilities and application-level Linux system calls before even starting to work on kernel code.

Comment: i solved it thanks. I added the toolchain path wrong. Now, i add the right one and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug and understand your `Makefile`. Invoke it as `remake -x -d` it will give you a lot of debugging output, while behaving otherwise as [GNU make](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/).

As I commented, don't forget to use `$(MAKE)` instead of `make` inside your `Makefile`.

Regarding the error: `angstrom-linux-gnueabi-gcc: not found` you need to install the appropriate cross-compiler (and cross-linker) toolchain on your system (or perhaps set appropriately your `PATH` environment variable, so that it would be found).

<sup>All this won't solve your problem, but will help you understanding it</sup>